# Ant in Groovy: Copying a single file

Tags: ant, groovy, copy

I know that when using Ant from Groovy, you can do something like the following to copy files:

```
copy(todir:myDir) {
  fileset(dir:"src/test") {
    include(name:"**/*.groovy")
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient, and elegant way to copy a single file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
new AntBuilder().copy( file:"$sourceFile.canonicalPath", 
                           tofile:"$destFile.canonicalPath")
```

Comment: what to do if I want copy file with a folder hierarchy?

Comment: You can use the full power of the [ant copy task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).